# the gaps between values of a positive binary quadratic form at integer points

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Suppose that $s$ is a positive irrational number. Consider all possible values of the sum $x^2+sy^2$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers. These values form a set $W=\{0=w_1<w_2<\ldots\}$. Can the gaps $w_{k+1}-w_k$, $k=1,2,\ldots$, always remain smaller than a constant $C(s)$?

Comment: A pointer to the literature, even if you are probably already aware of this: P. Sarnak: 
Values at integers of binary quadratic forms. In: Harmonic analysis and number theory (Montreal, PQ, 1996), 181–203, CMS Conf. Proc., 21, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1997.